# Installing Linux on a (By Default) 4 Partition Laptop

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, recovery-partition

I have a Toshiba laptop and am trying to partition it to install Linux Mint. The issue is that somehow Toshiba laptops already come with 4 primary partitions, making it impossible to create another to put the linux distro on.

The 4 partitions are:

1. System
2. C: (Windows 7)
3. C: (hidden Windows 7 partition)
4. HDDRECOVERY

I believe the HDDRECOVERY partition is a Toshiba thing.

I have tentatively decided that the easiest thing would be to delete the HDDRECOVERY partition so that I can create another partition for Linux.

My question is, are there any/what are the risks involved in deleting the "recovery" partition? Could something bad happen? If so, what should I do? Delete a different partition?

**EDIT** If the recovery partition is important if I screw with the computer somehow, what other options do I have to get linux on my laptop? Windows is unbearable ...

Comment: It's probably partition containing backup of your Windows 7 system, so it's your choice, if you don't need recovery or you have your own elsewhere, you may delete it.

Comment: @week Could you post as answer? Perhaps including alternatives?

Comment: Why the downvote? At least explain (to anonymous downvoter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably partition containing backup of your Windows 7 system, so it's your choice, if you don't need recovery or you have your own elsewhere, you may delete it.

Default Windows (>=Vista) installation contains two partitions, one with Bootloader (about 100MB) and one with System itself. It's also possible to have both in one.

Almost all OEM installations contains some sort of backup made by manufacturer, which is a replacement of physical system media. This is probably your case. It's not important to running your computer, it's just backup of clean Windows 7 install.

If you didn't create those partitions, then I presume that partitions contain:

1. Boot partition
2. Windows system partition
3. Windows PE for Toschiba's recovery
4. Partition containing backup itself

To check if it's actual state. You may boot with live distro and go through those partitions. Or try to mount those partitions with `diskmgmt.msc` under Windows.

Comment: I ended up taking out there HDDRECOVERY  partition